# Loopback - Filter results of GET based on User

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have 3 models basically setup:

Contractor (extends User Model)
Company
Ticket

Ticket belongsTo Contractor, also Belongs to Company
Contractor hasMany Companies 
Company hasMany Contractors

Basically a Contractor can create a ticket. When he does so he'll pass in his contractorId and CompanyID he works for.

What I'm trying to achieve is being able to retrieve all tickets belonging to that Contractor when he is logged in and requests a GET on /tickets.

Similiarly, if a Company admin logs in, they should be able to retrieve all tickets that are attributed to that Company.

I presume I would setup some remote methods, but how do I do the filtering based on the ContractorId or Company the Contractor is attached to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous. Loopback models has find method which accept filter as argument as used in the WHERE clause in common SQL. 
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data

If you were asking about get the current user id, see this doc
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Using+current+context
User id can be retrieved from the token instance.

Most of all, I recommend you to follow the every starting guide of loopback document. Filtering model is not a special task, so it looks like you skipped to read some important guide doc.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's not worded correctly. I know how to filter to get the info, what I am after is how to stop contractors retrieving other contractors tickets.

Comment: So for instance, if my contractor ID was 1, I could easily get my tickets by going to /contractors/1/tickets. However, how do I stop a user from requesting /contractors/2/tickets and getting the tickets of Contractor with ID 2.

Comment: Read this. Especially, ACLs part. (Access control)https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Hiddenproperties

Comment: When you create your preject and run, loopback automatically run api explorer.          http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Use-API-Explorer.  It may helps you a lot when testing.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this, the answer lies in Accessing Related Models.

http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Accessing-related-models.html

The methods are outlined there and can be used in ACLS.